# How to use the join() function (for arrays) without commas

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I was wondering how to use the join function for arrays in JavaScript without it returning commas.

Example:

```
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c']
alphabet.join();
// returns a,b,c
```

How do i make it so it doesn't return the commas?

Comment: MDN: [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Come on!!...how hard is it to search for javascript join and find documentation or examples? Show some effort before posting, this shouldn't be your first line of research

Answer (score 2):

Just specify an empty string for the join:

```
alphabet.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.join(separator);
```

if you don't want commas, use

```
alphabet.join('');
```